# Angular directives in cached template not binding properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Given this directive:

```
myApp.directive('someDirective', ['$compile', '$templateCache', function($compile, $templateCache) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function(scope, element, attr) {

            // Load a template.
            var template = $templateCache.get("partials/foo.html");

            $compile(template)(scope);
            $(element).append(template);

        }
    };

}]);
```

and given `foo.html`:

```
<div data-foo>Some Text</div>
```

and the `foo` directive:

```
myApp.directive('foo', [function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            console.log('foo1');

            $(element).on('click', function() {
                console.log('foo2');
            });

        }
    };

}]);
```

I will always see `foo1` in my console but never `foo2` when I click on the added element. In fact, though I can see the added elements just fine and can `console.log()` them just fine, I am unable to ever bind any handlers to them. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div will have no height unless you put something in it. Change your div to this:

```
<div data-foo>Some content</div>
```

Also you need to make the template an element, do this as well right after you create it:

```
template = angular.element(template);
```

Here's a jsFiddle showing you: http://jsfiddle.net/c3Wuu/

As a side note, you should not be wiring up a click event, or building a template like this. Have a look at some videos and do angular tutorial unless you know what you're doing.

**Edit**
This is how you would wire it up using angular practices

in foo directive html:

```
<div data-foo>
    <span data-ng-click="clickOne()">Click One</span>
    <span data-ng-click="clickTwo()">Click Two</span>
</div>
```

In foo link function:

```
scope.clickOne = function(){
   console.log("click one");
};
scope.clickTwo = function(){
   console.log("click two");
};
```

By wiring up your own click function you are circumventing the point of angular.

Comment: The height is not the issue, this was sample code. `foo.html` could contain links, etc., none of which are properly bound. What's wrong with binding a click event to an element in a directive? I've done many Angular tutorials but I'm open to anything specific that you can share.

Comment: Height would be an issue in this sample code. Regardless I've modified my answer to answer the second part of your comment. Did what I suggest initially fix your problem?

Comment: `template = angular.element(template);` does indeed solve it! Thank you very much. What does that do to the element that `$compile` doesn't already provide? According to the docs I have read, `angular.element()` is simply Angular+jqLite's version of the jQuery `$` wrapper. I'm very familiar with the `ng-click` directive and use it liberally, but there are instances where you may want your own directive to handle complex use cases including `element` click bindings – an example: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/3ac3b4874656bce724490ad54f418ff0773fe9b8/src/dropdown/dropdown.js#L12